# question about highlighted parts of this passage

Tags: word-meaning

> So imagine my surprise, my joy, when I suddenly got a father doll as a gift! My uncle had bought it for me on a business trip to Bulgaria. It was a beautiful doll, just the right size, a little shorter than the mother and the grandmother but taller than the kid. It had a hard body and a face made of soft, **squeezable** plastic, **painted in masculine shades of brown** . Brown eyes, brown lips, brown nostrils. Brown hair made out of some very hairlike material. A perpetual warm brown smile. It was dressed in what appeared to be a Bulgarian national costume of felt hat and boots, rumpled cotton pants, embroidered shirt, and a leather belt. This was exactly how I imagined an ideal father would look.
>
> The father doll had only one imperfection—a bad hip. His left leg wouldn’t stay in place. It kept detaching from his torso and dangling in his pants. But I loved the doll so much that I didn’t see even this as a shortcoming until Tania pointed it out.

I would like to translate this text into my mother language, could you simplify **painted in masculine shades of brown** and **squeezable** ? It is difficult to understand for me.

1. Does the word "squeezable" mean able ti be squeezed?
2. Does **painted in masculine shades of brown** mean **lines of brown that provokes a feeling of being a male** ?

Comment: **[shade](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/shade#shade_11)** "[countable] a particular form of a color. For example sky blue and navy blue are shades of blue"

Comment: Squeezable plastic = pliant, not rigid, plastic.  "masculine shades of brown" = colors|hues that are conventionally associated with males (in a given culture). In the US, for example, the color pink is conventionally associated with girls and blue with boys. When a baby is born, if it's a boy, the mother does not typically receive gifts of little pink sweaters but little blue sweaters, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"painted in a masculine shade of brown" - a shade of a colour means that it's a certain kind, like olive green and pale green are different shades of green. I'd say it does not provoke a feeling of being male, it makes the doll look masculin.

"squeezable" - It's an adjective to describe a soft toy, so yes, it means "able to be squeezed", I suppose.

By the way, can you tell us what your native language is (I suspect it is German?), there might be some people who are able to translate it for you.

Comment: persian it is my language

Comment: @user3784090/ Welcome to ELL. If you are not sure that your answer is correct,  as suggested by your 'I suppose', then it's better not to post it here. Doubtful answers mean that other members need to comment on their correctness. As an English language site, we don't offer a translation service.